# SSH does not use PublicKey on CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, ssh, centos6

I have a CentOS 6.3 server and with a user named ako.
I am running Kubuntu 12.10 as my client and I have copied my public key to the server using the `ssh-copy-id` command.
I have updated the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file with these values:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
StrictModes yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

But, when I try to login to the server, I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have setup SSH many many times before without problems, but I have no idea why this one does not work!!

**EDIT**
This is the output of `ssh` ran in verbose mode:

```
ssh ako@123.456.789.000 -v
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 123.456.789.000 [123.456.789.000] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ako/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/ako/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ako/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ako/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ako/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ako/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
debug1: Host '123.456.789.000' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ako/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ako/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ako/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ako/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run your ssh in verbose mode to see the specifics... It seems you're connecting as a different user... "ako"

Check the permissions on the home directory of the "ako" user on the destination system. `ssh-copy-id` should have done this for you, though.

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: After I ran the `restorecon` command, I ran these three commands, and finally, it's fixed!!!

Answer (score 2):

You've copied your id file from a system with `AppArmor` to a system with `SELinux`.
On the Centos 6.3 machine run either:

- `restorecon ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- `chcon  unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

In the end the context should look like.

> ls -Z .ssh/authorized_keys
>   -rw-------. user user unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 .ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: I would actually do restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh, to get all contexts right on the entire dir.

Comment: I ran the `restorecon` command on the CentOS, and the output of `ls` is the same, except for the permission which is `-rw-r--r--`. But still, I get the error.